# How do I add a new attribute to each ActiveRecord in array based on value from another array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, join, activerecord

as always you are irreplaceable when it comes to help. I got a new problem.

I have two Models.

```
User(id: integer)
Follower(id: integer, source_user_id: integer, target_user_id: integer)
```

I have `params[:user_id]` input via get.

I need to create an array of records that contains `is_following => true/false`.

`is_following` should be true when there is a Follower record present for `source_user_id = params[:user_id]`

`is_following` should be false when there is no Follower record present for this parameter

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you show some example data, the question is not that clear

Comment: I am looking for a list of users that specifies whether a particular user with params[:user_id] is following each or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

User Model modification

```
has_many :followers, class_name: 'Follower', foreign_key: :target_user_id

def is_followed? follower_id
    followers.where(:source_user_id => follower_id).exists?
end
```

And API

```
users = users.map {|user| { user: user, is_following: user.is_followed?(params[:user_id]) } }
```

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer to add a method in your *User* model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :followers, foreign_key: :source_user_id

   def is_following? follower_id
     follower_ids.include? follower_id.to_i
   end
end
```

and then:

```
user.is_following? params[:user_id]
```

The association was assumed based on your question.
Please note, that this is a short answer to your question. You probably want to redesign your associations, move the method into a [Decorator](http://www.chrisrolle.com/blog/a-decorator-implementation) (depending on your use case) and maybe optimize the querying.

Comment: Thanks, however only some of your code was correct.

Comment: First of all, the answer was more intended to give you an idea, since your question had no real code snippet included to base on. Please rephrase your question with valid code snippets, to refer on.

Comment: Thank you for helping! However, it's not fair to the other user to give you the credit. He also gave a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to reflect the clarification on what you want.

Define a helper function within the `User` model, called is_following:

```
def is_following?
  !Follower.where(source_user_id: self.id).empty?
end
```

Now, you can use the map method to create an array. You'll have to have an array of hashes, since users don't have any kind of attribute to store the boolean value:

```
User.all.map { |user| {user: user, is_following: user.is_following? } }
```

Comment: I am not looking for a list of followers. I am looking for a list of users that specifies whether a particular user following each or not.

Comment: So use the second solution

Comment: I don't understand what it does. I need a list of user objects, the second one makes a list of Follower objects.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it's very clear what you want. Do you need a lit of users, with an attribute to say whether they're being followed?

Comment: Yes, followed by the user given at params[:user_id].

Comment: Where do the followers come into it?

Comment: It's a side record that keeps track who follows who so if you have one user follow the other. The record will be Follower.new(:source_user_id => 1, :target_user_id =>2) meaning user 1 follows user 2. However only User objects contains stuff like username and picture. Also, is_following is not defined as a model attribute. It needs to be an accessor or something. I just don't know enough rails how to do it.

Comment: See my edits, hopefully that's more like what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, however only some of your code was correct.

Comment: I'm not trying to write your code for you. I'm trying to help to show you how you might implement something like this, and leave the rest up to you. Please be more appreciative when people spend time trying to help you, and if you want to be a developer, expect to have to do some of the work yourself.

Comment: Thank you for helping! However, it's not fair to the other user to give you the credit. He also gave a little bit.